# Installing Jenkins with Puppet fails to import GPG key

Tags: puppet, jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins with Puppet using the manifests below.

```
    # init.pp
    class jenkins {
      include jenkins::install, jenkins::service
    }

    # service.pp
    class jenkins::service {
      service { "jenkins":
        ensure     => running,
        hasstatus  => true,
        hasrestart => true,
        enable     => true,
        require    => Class["jenkins::install"],
      }
    }

    # install.pp
    class jenkins::install {
      include jenkins::install::repo
      include jenkins::install::java

      package { "jenkins":
        ensure  => present,
        require => Class['jenkins::install::repo','jenkins::install::java'],
      }
    }

    # install/repo.pp
    class jenkins::install::repo {
      file { "/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/jenkins-ci.org.key":
        owner  => root,
        group  => root,
        mode   => 0600,
        source => "puppet:///jenkins/jenkins-ci.org.key"
      }

      yumrepo { "jenkins":
        baseurl  => "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat",
        descr    => "Jenkins",
        enabled  => 1,
        gpgcheck => 1,
        gpgkey   => "file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/jenkins-ci.org.key",
        require  => File["/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/jenkins-ci.org.key"]
      }
    }

    # install/java.pp
    class jenkins::install::java {
      package { "java-1.6.0-openjdk":
        ensure => present,
      }
    }
```

The repo is added and the key written to the file system. However, I get the following error.

```
    err: /Stage[main]/Jenkins::Install/Package[jenkins]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install jenkins' returned 1: warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID d50582e6
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
        yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
      File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 309, in user_main
        errcode = main(args)
      File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 261, in main
        return_code = base.doTransaction()
      File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 410, in doTransaction
        if self.gpgsigcheck(downloadpkgs) != 0:
      File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 510, in gpgsigcheck
        self.getKeyForPackage(po, lambda x, y, z: self.userconfirm())
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3519, in getKeyForPackage
        keys = self._retrievePublicKey(keyurl, repo)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 3484, in _retrievePublicKey
        keys_info = misc.getgpgkeyinfo(rawkey, multiple=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/misc.py", line 375, in getgpgkeyinfo
        raise ValueError(str(e))
    ValueError: unknown pgp packet type 17 at 706
```

This suggests to me that the key isn't being imported successfully, and `rpm -qa gpg-pubkey` doesn't show the key. If I manually `yum install jenkins` without the key imported I get the same error. With the key imported, the manual installation succeeds.

I'm successfully installing other yum repos and keys standalone (basically the `install/repo.pp` manifest as its own module), such as EPEL, but as this repo is only for Jenkins I wanted to include it in my Jenkins module.

Is there something wrong with my manifests? Or some other problem?

**UPDATE**:

The following manifest results in the jenkins and epel repos being installed, `rpm -qa gpg-pub*` shows the epel key but not the jenkins key, and git is installed but not jenkins.

```
    class jenkins { 
      yumrepo {"jenkins":
        baseurl  => "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat",
        descr    => "Jenkins",
        enabled  => 1,
        gpgcheck => 1,
        gpgkey   => "http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key",
      }
      package {"jenkins":
        ensure  => latest,
        require => Yumrepo["jenkins"]
      }
    }

    class git { 
      yumrepo {"epel":
        baseurl  => "http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/5/i386",
        descr    => "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL)",
        enabled  => 1,
        gpgcheck => 1,
        gpgkey   => "http://keys.gnupg.net:11371/pks/lookup?search=0x217521F6&op=get",
      }
      package {"git":
        ensure  => latest,
        require => Yumrepo["epel"]
      }
    }

    include jenkins
    include git
```

**UPDATE**:

Should have included software versions:

- CentOS 5.7
- ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25)
- Puppet v2.7.9
- yum-3.2.22
- rpm-4.4.2.3

Comment: For a workaround, see [this thread on the puppet users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/puppet-users/Yxiekm0j1J4)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that rpm has problems importing the Jenkins key because it contains a JPEG image.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880

packet type 17 is an image:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.12

```
> gpg --list-keys D50582E6
pub   1024D/D50582E6 2009-02-01
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi 
uid                  Kohsuke Kawaguchi 
uid                  [jpeg image of size 3704]
sub   2048g/10AF40FE 2009-02-01
```

It seems that RPM doesn't know what to do with it.

```
> sudo rpm --import jenkins-ci.org.key 
[sudo] password for me: 
error: jenkins-ci.org.key: import read failed(-1).
```

Googling around for any known issues for RPM doesn't turn up anything obvious, but maybe this gives you a direction.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I'm able to manually import the key without issue, it's only Puppet that fails to import the key.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your simplified manifest on:

- CentOS 6.2
- ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352)
- Puppet v2.7.9
- yum-3.2.29-22.el6
- rpm-4.8.0-19.el6

Both repos are added successfully.

From the error message, it does look like the error message is coming from yum, not puppet or anything else.

Can you provide a similar description of your environment?
Probably most important is the version of yum.

Try upgrading it to at least 3.2.29 (latest stable 3.2.x). 
Changelog is [here](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/whatsnew/3.2.29), references some *significant fixes* relating to GPG keys.

Comment: You're right that the error is coming from yum and just being passed on by Puppet, as I get the same error when I install without importing the key. I definitely should have included version information, especially as my versions are significantly older. I'll update the question to include versions and see if updating yum makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. Have you tried updating yum to the latest version yet?

Comment: I ran `yum update yum` and got 3.2.22-39, which still failed in the same way. I'm investigating upgrading yum to 3.2.29 and will report back.

Comment: It looks like the Centos.Redhat 5.x branch won't go beyond yum 3.2.22, so you might want to ask for a backport from RedHat's Bugzilla.

Comment: Thanks again for your help (and super quick responses), I might go with a workaround pure Puppet solution.

Comment: Or move to CentOS 6.2. ;) It's great. Also, if the questioned is answered, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Yeah, I don't have control over the distro (which I think is pretty much the case for anyone one CentOS 5.x :) Though I appreciate the help, I can't really say that your answer was correct because I can't easily upgrade yum enough to see. See the link in my comment on the question for the basis of the workaround I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to add and `rpm --import <PUBKEY>` command in your manifest.

The Exec type reference documentation is [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/exec.html).

Perhaps you can try adding `assumeyes=1` to the repo file, together with the gpgkey option this should add the key automatically.

Comment: It seems strange that Puppet manages to import the EPEL key but it has to be done manually with the Jenkins key.

Answer (score 0):

This is super after-the-fact but here's what I ended up going with:

```
if ($::operatingsystemmajrelease == '5'){
  exec { 'EL5 Jenkins Key Workaround':
    command  => 'rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins-ci.org.key',
    unless   => "rpm -qa --nodigest --nosignature --qf '%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE} %{SUMMARY}\n' | grep d50582e6",
    path     => ['/bin', '/usr/bin'],
  }
}
```

I added a PR to add this workaround to the official module:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/puppet-jenkins/pull/344/files

Longer breakdown here:

http://dan.carley.co/blog/2012/05/22/yum-gpg-keys-for-jenkins/